# can sombody assis with installing symfony please?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

yikes i have forgotten but am following:

```
http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/03-Symfony-Installation
```

i have a jobeet directory and want to install symfony-1.4.16 here.
i downloaded symfony-1.4.16.tgz and unpacked it with tar zxpf symfony-1.4.16.tgz
then moved it mv symfony-1.4.16 symfony
and removed the tgz with rm symfony-1.4.16.tgz
i have this now:

```
helloises@helloise:~/jobeet$ ls -lah
total 7.2M
drwxr-xr-x  3 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-09 15:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 83 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-09 14:59 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises 593K 1970-01-01 11:13 package.xml
-rwxr-xr-x  1 helloises helloises 3.6M 2012-01-04 09:13 symfony-1.2.12.tgz (is in GREEN)
drwxr-xr-x  5 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-09 15:06 symfony            (is in BLUE)
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises 3.1M 2012-01-09 15:05 symfony-1.4.16.tgz (is in RED)
```

huh? dont know what is going on here.. i unpacked version 1.4.16
i run:

```
helloises@helloise:~/jobeet$ ./symfony generate:project jobeet --orm=Propel
bash: ./symfony: is a directory
```

any help please?
thanks

Comment: symfony 1.4.16 is out, why don't you use it? http://www.symfony-project.org/installation/1_4

Comment: isnt 1.4.2 newer than 1.4.16? the symfony i use on my other project is 1.4.2

Comment: No, because 16 > 2 (as integers, of course)

Comment: ha ha ha oooh ok..oops any case let me try that and see what happens

Comment: nope still not..symfony is listed as a directory, thus in blue, and not in green as an executable...something aint right :(

Comment: you're supposed to put this directory in lib/vendor and follow these instructions : http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/04-Project-Setup . You should remove symfony-1.2.12.tgz

Comment: sorted thank you i had an old jobeet directory i just made a new dir and copied over from there..it is an old version though but it will suffice for what i need it for :)

Comment: oo so the tutorial steps wont work if i put it in another directory other than lib/vendor?? anycase its sorted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a *lib/vendor* folder. The *symfony* folder must be under the *vendor* folder (*/wherever_my_project_is/lib/vendor/symfony*).

The go up two levels (so you can see the *lib* folder (if you do a `ls`) and run

`php lib/vendor/symfony/data/bin/symfony -V`

If everything is ok, that should return the symfony version.

Then you can generate a new project:

```
php lib/vendor/symfony/data/bin/symfony generate:project PROJECT_NAME
```

That will create the necessary directory structure and also make the symfony executabile for you (in your project directory). See more [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/03-Running-Symfony). I recommend reading [A Gentle Introduction to symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/) tutorial.